# customized url routing in rails 2.3.5 How can i have url format with space or underscore in it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I am using rails 2.3.5 .

I need to have a url format like

```
/:first_name{space}:last_name  # e.g.: /Michael Jackson

/:first_name{_}:last_name      # e.g.: /Michael_Jackson
```

Currently iam having this as the format which works

```
map.shorturl "/:first_name.:last_name", :controller => 'users', :action => 'show' ex: Michael.Jackson
```

The dot in between is working.. but the other two formats are not working.

Is it possible to have those formats? if yes, how?

Comment: space MUST be encoded, as %20 or + [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/497908/are-urls-allowed-to-have-a-space-in-them)

Comment: I tried both the %20 or +  both are not working.             map.shorturl "/:first_name%20:last_name", :controller => 'deceased_users', :action => 'show'  .. I tried the parenthesis also but no luck      map.shorturl "/(:first_name)_(:last_name)", :controller => 'deceased_users', :action => 'show'.  , but the . i working

Answer (score 0):

For spaces i'm pretty sure you will have to encode to %20 or +. See link on comment.

For "_" you can enclose the parameters in parentheses to make rails treat each part as a different one [another SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11962006/rails-routing-with-a-letter-as-separator).

Are you sure the dot separated form is working well? I'm not sure but i would bet that rails will try to use the second parameter as format